# How do I resolve a DFS replication issue when the replication service thinks the destination disk is full, but actually isn't?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs-r

I ran a diagnostic report on my DFS replication between 2 servers and got the following error in my report:

```
The DFS Replication service stopped replication on volume D:. This failure can occur because the disk is full, the disk is failing, or a quota limit has been reached. Event ID: 2004
```

Event ID 2004 doesn't even show up in the destination server's event logs.

I checked the `D:` drive on the destination server, and it has plenty of available space; 4TB.  Even the DFS Diagnostic Report shows there's plenty of space.

I checked the permissions of the destination `D:` drive, and `SYSTEM` has full permissions on the drive and the directory I'm trying to replicate.

I checked the Hardware Event logs, and there are no errors.

Am I missing something?

How do I resolve a DFS replication problem when the replication service thinks the destination disk is full, but actually isn't?